`source` in bash breaks with one of the apparently identical files
I have two files which look apparently identical (link here). I don't seem to find any difference between the two. However, on running source env-setup.sh, which is one of the files, bash runs happily. But running source env-setup-ioannis.sh, which is the other file, bash complains with the following error message: : command not found. Can someone please help me find out the issue?
I tried source env-setup.sh on one of the files and source env-setup-ioannis.sh with the other. I expected both of them to run fine. However, the latter showed the following error : command not found and also broke the environment variables.

link to env-setup.sh: https://file.io/RmH5HduHxh9M
link to en-setup-ioannnis.sh: https://file.io/qPd2LgHbXCPX

The file you get errors from has DOS newlines

I don't know the difference between a newline and a DOS newline. printing these lines and reading them individually on Python seems to give the same output. Even utilities, like meld, say they are the same. I don't know exactly what program what program was used to create the problem-causing file. But this was created on Windows and accessed by bash source in a WSL environment.

DOS newlines are two character sequences, a CR + a LF; UNIX newlines are LF-only. The CR is thus seen as part of the line you're running as a command when parsed by UNIXy tools. Answers on the linked duplicate tell you how to solve this.
